# Переименование ключей в объекте

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Дан объект:

```
{
  "0": {       
    "matches": 3,
    "team_id": "115"
  },
  "1": {       
    "matches": 3,
    "team_id": "116"
  },
  "2": {       
    "matches": 3,
    "team_id": "117"
  },
  "3": {        
    "matches": 3,
    "team_id": "119"
  },
}
```

Нужно заменить ключи (индексы) каждого вложенного объекта на значение свойства его team_id. В итоге должно получиться следующее:

```
{
  "115": {        
    "matches": 3,
    "team_id": "115"
  },
  "116": {        
    "matches": 3,
    "team_id": "116"
  },
  "117": {        
    "matches": 3,
    "team_id": "117"
  },
  "119": {        
    "matches": 3,
    "team_id": "119"
  },
}
```

Я нашла несколько разных способов для переименования ключей в объектах, но они не сработали.
Подскажите, как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: А есть пример вложенного "массива"?

Comment: Прошу прощения, конечно, это объект. Я не очень хорошо знаю javascript и еще несколько путаюсь в понятиях. Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Ну не бывают объекты многомерными...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
  "0": {
    matches: 3,
    team_id: "115"
  },
  "1": {
    matches: 3,
    team_id: "116"
  },
  "2": {
    matches: 3,
    team_id: "117"
  },
  "3": {
    matches: 3,
    team_id: "119"
  }
};

for (let key in obj) {
  obj[obj[key].team_id] = obj[key];
  delete obj[key];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: какой обьект был дан для такого и написал

Comment: А вы до конца дочитайте текст вопроса

Comment: Это действительно сработало. Прошу прощения за неточную формулировку вопроса. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @РустамГимранов, ну и какое это решение? `{
  "0": {
    matches: 3,
    team_id: "0"
  }
}` - это раз. `{
  "0": {
    matches: 3,
    team_id: "1"
  },
  "1": {
    matches: 3,
    team_id: "116"
  }
}` - это два. И подозреваю, что это не всё.